# Unable to instantiate Object in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a class called 'Repository' which instantiates some sample classes with data:

```
public class Repository
{
    // create dictionary collection for prices, and define property to get the collection
    Dictionary<string, int> prices = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    public Dictionary<string, int> Prices { get { return prices; } }

    // create List with Reservations, and define property to get the List 
    List<Reservation> reservations = new List<Reservation>();
    public List<Reservation> Reservations { get { return reservations; } }
    public Repository()
    {

        // add prices to the dictionary, prices
        prices.Add("Dog", 180);
        prices.Add("Cat", 140);
        prices.Add("Snake", 120);
        prices.Add("Guinea pig", 75);
        prices.Add("Canary", 60);

        // create customers
        Customer c1 = new Customer(1, "Susan", "Peterson", "Borgergade 45", "8000", "Aarhus", "supe@xmail.dk", "21212121");
        Customer c2 = new Customer(2, "Brian", "Smith", "Algade 108", "8000", "Aarhus", "brsm@xmail.dk", "45454545");
        Reservation r1 = new Reservation(1, "Hamlet", new DateTime(2014, 9, 2), "Dog", new DateTime(2014, 9, 20), new DateTime(2014, 9, 20), c1);
        Reservation r2 = new Reservation(2, "Dog", new DateTime(2014, 9, 14), "Samson", new DateTime(2014, 9, 21), new DateTime(2014, 9, 21), c1);
        Reservation r3 = new Reservation(3, "Cat", new DateTime(2014, 9, 7), "Darla", new DateTime(2014, 9, 10), new DateTime(2014, 9, 10), c2);

        // add Reservations to list of Reservations with instance name reservations
        reservations.Add(r1);
        reservations.Add(r2);
        reservations.Add(r3);
    }
}
```

Now I want to display that data in a view, so I try to instantiate it in `ReservationController` and make it available to the View:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    private Repository repository = new Repository();
    return View(repository.Reservations);
}
```

This produces a couple of errors on the line where I try to instantiate the Repository:

> The type or namespace name 'Repository' could not be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> ; expected
>
> Invalid expression term 'private'

Comment: Thanks for not cluttering the question with the _actual_ build error. Or where it occurs.

Comment: I only see Prices property on your Repository type.  Yet you reference a Reservations property?

Comment: @SonicTheLichen, I added an ending bracket to the Repository class when I made my edit (mostly to let VS do the formatting). Although this means that there was more to the class that wasn't posted, it doesn't change the fact that _it wasn't posted_.

Comment: @Severin, did you post this questin **and** vote to close it? Why not just fix the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is invalid to assign an *access modifier* to a local variable hence the error.

You need to remove the `private` access modifier from the local variable.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  Repository repository = new Repository();
  return View(repository.Reservations);
}
```

Comment: I noticed that you retracted your accept vote. I am just wondering why? The answer is not particularly impressive, I know, but it *does* answer the question.